# Why does takewhile() skip the first line?

Tags: python, io, generator

I have a file like this:

```
1
2
3
TAB
1
2
3
TAB
```

I want to read the lines between TAB as blocks.

```
import itertools

def block_generator(file):
    with open(file) as lines:
        for line in lines:
            block = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x.rstrip('\n') != '\t',
                                             lines))
            yield block
```

I want to use it as such:

```
blocks = block_generator(myfile)
for block in blocks:
    do_something(block)
```

The blocks i get all start with the second line like `[2,3] [2,3]`, why?

Comment: the for loop is eating the first line of each block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another approach using groupby

```
from itertools import groupby
def block_generator(filename):
    with open(filename) as lines:
        for pred,block in groupby(lines, "\t\n".__ne__):
            if pred:
                yield block
```

Comment: Hi @gnibbler, you code may works fine for small files. I have a very big file I do not want to read them all at a time. But thanks for your code.

Comment: @gstar, why do you think my code reads the whole file at once?

Comment: Why not just `for x, y in groupby(lines, "\t\n".__ne__): if x: yield list(y)`? (I was going to say "why not just return the generator expression", but I guess that results in the context manager triggering prematurely...) (I was surprised to find that `groupby` does not collate groups with the same key...)

Comment: @Karl, yeah that's nicer I think. and yes you need to yield inside the with block to prevent the file being closed prematurely

Comment: @gnibbler,  real groupby() should be a global Operation on the whole list, it must somehow first read all the lines in. But you are right here, groupby() in pythong is a change detector.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, tested code.  Uses `while True:` to loop, and lets `itertools.takewhile()` do everything with `lines`.  When `itertools.takewhile()` reaches the end of input, it returns an iterator that does nothing except raise `StopIteration`, which `list()` simply turns into an empty list, so a simple `if not block:` test detects the empty list and breaks out of the loop.

```
import itertools

def not_tabline(line):
    return '\t' != line.rstrip('\n')

def block_generator(file):
    with open(file) as lines:
        while True:
            block = list(itertools.takewhile(not_tabline, lines))
            if not block:
                break
            yield block

for block in block_generator("test.txt"):
    print "BLOCK:"
    print block
```

As noted in a comment below, this has one flaw: if the input text has two lines in a row with just the tab character, this loop will stop processing without reading all the input text.  And I cannot think of any way to handle this cleanly; it's really unfortunate that the iterator you get back from `itertools.takewhile()` uses `StopIteration` *both* as the marker for the end of a group and as what you get at end-of-file.  To make it worse, I cannot find any way to ask a file iterator object whether it has reached end-of-file or not.  And to make it even worse, `itertools.takewhile()` seems to advance the file iterator to end-of-file instantly; when I tried to rewrite the above to check on our progress using `lines.tell()` it was already at end-of-file after the first group.

I suggest using the `itertools.groupby()` solution.  It's cleaner.

Comment: Great, I shoud try using your code. Thanks. I do not know, if Regex can also do the job.

Comment: Won't 2 consecutive lines of TAB create an empty block too?

Comment: @Paul McGuire, that is a truly excellent point.  I think the `itertools.groupby()` answer is cleaner and doesn't have this flaw.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are taking `lines` in your lambda function rather than `line`. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.takewhile` implicitly iterates over the `lines` of the file in order to grab chunks, but so does `for line in lines:`. Each time through the loop, a `line` is grabbed, thrown away (since there is no code that uses `line`), and then some more are `block`ed together.

Comment: hi Karl, I have thought about that. After the first takewhile() the file pointer point at TAB line, after I processed the first block, "for" move the file pointer to the next line,'1' and give it to takewhile(). It should be right.but...

Comment: The for loop does not "move a file pointer"; that is the wrong way to think about it. It iterates over lines of the file. The first time through the loop, `line` is equal to `'1\n'`. That value has been consumed, and is no longer available for `takewhile()`.

Comment: Ok.I see it. So 'code'takewhile() consumed TAB line. Then 'code'for consumed '1\n' line, so 'code'takewhile() get lines from '2\n'. great.