# Iterator using itertools is skipping a line

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, iterator, python-itertools

I have the feeling that my question is related to [Why does takewhile() skip the first line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278327/why-does-takewhile-skip-the-first-line)

I haven't found satisfactory answers in there though.

My examples below use the following modules

```
import csv
from itertools import takewhile
```

Here is my problem.
I have a csv file which I want to parse using itertools.

For instance, i want to separate the header from the content.
This is spotted by the presence of a keyword in the first column.

Here is `file.csv` example

```
a, content
b, content
KEYWORD, something else
c, let's continue
```

The two first lines compose the header of the file.
The `KEYWORD` line separates it from the content: the last line.

Even, if it is not properly part of the content, I want to parse the separation row.

```
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = takewhile(lambda x: x[0] != 'KEYWORD', reader)
    for row in header:
        print(row)
    print('End of header')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

I was not expecting this, but the `KEYWORD` line is skipped.
As you will see in the following output:

```
['a', ' content']
['b', ' content']
End of header
['c', " let's continue"]
```

I have tried simulating the csv reader to see if it was coming from there.
But apparently not.
The following code produces the same behavior.

```
l = [['a', 'content'],
    ['b','content'],
    ['KEYWORD', 'something else'],
    ['c', "let's continue"]]

i = iter(l)
header = takewhile(lambda x: x[0] != 'KEYWORD', i)
for row in header:
    print(row)
print('End of header')
for row in i:
    print(row)
```

How can I do to use the feature of takewhile, while preventing the following for the skip the unparsed line ?

As I have understood, the first `for` calls for `next` on the iterator, to test its content.
The second calls for `next` once again, to gather the value.
And the separation row is hence skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe, I came to question myself on some trick to code.
Here is what I reached :

```
class RewindableFile(file):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        nb_backup = kwargs.pop('nb_backup', 1)
        super(RewindableFile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._nb_backup = nb_backup
        self._backups = []
        self._time_anchor = 0

    def next(self):
        if self._time_anchor >= 0:
            item = super(RewindableFile, self).next()
            self._backup(item)
            return item
        else:
            item = self._forward()
            return item

    def rewind(self):
        self._time_anchor = self._time_anchor - 1
        time_bound = min(self._nb_backup, len(self._backups))
        if self._time_anchor < -time_bound:
            raise Exception('You have gone too far in history...')

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def _backup(self, row):
        self._backups.append(row)
        extra_items = len(self._backups) - self._nb_backup
        if extra_items > 0:
            del self._backups[0:extra_items]

    def _forward(self):
        item = self._backups[self._time_anchor]
        self._time_anchor = self._time_anchor + 1
        return item
```

And how I use it :

```
with RewindableFile('csv.csv', 'rb') as f:
    def test_kwd_and_rewind(x):
        if x[0] != 'KEYWORD':
            return True
        else:
            f.rewind()
            return False

    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = takewhile(test_kwd_and_rewind, reader)
    for row in header:
        print(row)
    print('End of header')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

I could have also overload `read` and `readline` functions to save the `jump`.
But I don't need them here.

Comment: Inspired on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539107/python-rewinding-one-line-in-file-when-iterating-with-f-next, and to save buffering operated naturally by `file`, I migrated from a `seek` to a backup one. I altered the code consequently.

Comment: Afterwards, the solution I quoted before is better. It decorates the file, instead of redefining it. Hence, I recommend their approach. While still adding some of my features as adaptive capacity of backup. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to restructure - `takewhile` isn't a good fit for what you are doing. The problem is that `takewhile` has to *read* the line starting `'KEYWORD'` to determine that it has reached a line it shouldn't take, and once the line is read the file's "read head" is at the start of the next line. Similarly, with `iter`, `takewhile` has already consumed (but discarded) the line starting `'KEYWORD'` when you start `for row in i`.

One alternative would be something like:

```
header = []
content = []
target = header
for row in reader:
    if line.startswith('KEYWORD'):
        target = content
    target.append(row)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have more tricky process than adding the content to a list. Hence your answer is not fully satisfactory to my problem. You lead me to rethink a bit of some workaround though. Thank you (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own takewhile like this.

```
def takewhile(predicate, iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        yield x
        if not predicate(x):
            break
```

test:

```
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x:x!=3, range(10)))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: That would require takewhile to be able to access iterable next without consuming it. I can't see any possible approach on this side. That was my first intent before creating a RewindableFile. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

jonrsharpe has it right. This isn't quite a job for takewhile. itertools also has a groupby function which can more easily handle the splitting. The `LastHeader`class below keeps a record of the last header line passed through the `check` method, and returns a reference to it each time `check` is called.
This lets you run through the file a single time, without having to backtrack any.

```
class LastHeader():
    """Checks for new header strings. For use with groupby"""
    def __init__(self, sentinel='#'):
        self.sentinel = sentinel
        self.lastheader = ''

    def check(self, line):
        if line.startswith(self.sentinel):
            self.lastheader = line
        return self.lastheader

with open(fname, 'r') as fobj:
    lastheader = LastHeader(sentinel)
    for headerline, readlines in groupby(fobj, lastheader.check):
        foo(headerline)
        for line in readlines:
            bar(line)
```

where `foo` and `bar` are whatever processing you need to do on the headers and data.